# controlling the display of TDs in each TRs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement like this

Number of Rows generated in a table dependant on dynamically by user
In one scenario one TR will be there, some time 4 TRs or some time 8 TRs..

Maximum 10 TRs can be there and each TRs will have 6 Tds
Each TD will contain the Drop down items or radio buttons, 
Selection of each of item in the TD will trigger 
whether the next TD in that same row(TRs) is displayed or not.

TO implement the Above I am using the Div tags and with it, I am Hidding it or making it visible

The challenge I am facing

1) I am not able to create the Unique id for all the TD's in all the 10 TR's
because of which, if i hide one Class Id of one TD in 2nd TR, then it also 
hide the corresponding 2nd TDs in the next sequential TR's.

This is because of the Class Id I am genarating it programmatically in a FOR loop.

Can you please suggest me how I can proceed to implement this requirement???

2) Can we give the Id for the TD at run time??

Comment: So, you have to add dynamic columns and rows at runtime,this is your question right?

Comment: If you post your current code, people can suggest ways to improve it.

Comment: Some code would be helpful in assessing the possible solutions. In the interim I will imagine that the case is entirely written in JavaScript.

Comment: I have not started any thing yet, I am still working out the best ways to implement this requirement

Comment: @T J, Since i have not written the code I am unable to post it, I am checking the different ways to implement this requirement

Comment: @harigm, if you answer to my question i have some code, similar to this criteria that i will post it here.

Comment: If u have any link to the sample webpages where you could have seen the same functionality , please post here.. Atleast We can understand ur exact need.

Comment: @kalyan, yes I am adding rows dynamically, but in each row, columns are constant

Comment: Ok, I will post a sample code look at it.

Comment: @harigm i have a code which is in Asp.net and VB, but similar criteria. Do you want that to be posted here.

Comment: class and show/hide the `tr` then the `td`'s don't need to have unique ID's - would that work?

Comment: @kalyan, Please post that as an answer, let me check that

Comment: @harigm, i posted the code pls refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outline below is a very rudimentary element creation program. It will operate to create the HTML document based on certain user data. http://jsfiddle.net/3rvDk/

```
(function(){

    function get_element_id( elem ) {
        return Number(elem.id.split('_')[1]);
    }
    /**
     * build_guid_generator
     * 
     * @returns {Function} to generate global unique identifiers with
     */
    function build_guid_generator(){
        var named_ids = {};
        var i = 0;
        return function( ns ){
            named_ids[ns] = named_ids[ns] || 0;
            return named_ids[ns]++;
        };
    }
    var guid = build_guid_generator();
    /**
     * build_drop_down
     * 
     * creates a <select> HTML Element with global unique identifier
     * options is an object literal whose keys become the text of the option 
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} container
     * @param {Object} options
     * @param {Function} change_event - function to execute when the value is changed
     */
    function build_drop_down( container, options, change_event ) {
        var ddl = document.createElement('select');
        ddl.id = 'ddl_' + guid('ddl');
        for( var option in options ) if ( options.hasOwnProperty( option ) ) {

            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.text = option;
            opt.value = options[option];
            ddl.add(opt, null);

        }
        ddl.hide = function(){
            this.setAttribute('style','display:none;');
        };
        ddl.show = function(){
            this.setAttribute('style','');
        };
        container.appendChild( ddl );
        ddl.onchange = change_event;
        if ( get_element_id( ddl ) > 0 ) {
            ddl.setAttribute('style','display:none;');
        }
        return ddl;

    }
    /**
     * build_cell
     * 
     * creates a <td> HTML Element with global unique identifier and attaches to container
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} container
     */
    function build_cell ( container ) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.id = 'cell_' + guid('td');
        container.appendChild( td );
        return td;
    }
    /**
     * build_row
     * 
     * creates a <tr> HTML Element with global unique identifier and attaches to container
     * 
     * @param {HTMLElement} container
     */
    function build_row ( container ) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.id = 'row_' + guid('tr');
        container.appendChild( tr );
        return tr;
    }

    var user_data = {
        rows : 10,
        cells : 6,
        options : {
            'off' : false,
            'test' : 'value'
        }
    };

    function test_data_set ( data ) {

        var container = document.createElement('div');
        container.id = 'container';
        document.body.appendChild( container );

        var i = 0;
        for ( ; i < data.rows ; i++ ) {
            var tr = build_row( container ),
                j = 0;
            for( ; j < data.cells ; j++ ) {
                var td = build_cell( tr );
                build_drop_down( td, data.options, function( event ) {
                    console.log( this.value );
                    var next_sibling = document.getElementById( 'ddl_' + ( get_element_id( this ) + 1 ) );
                    console.log( next_sibling );
                    if ( this.value === 'false' ) {
                        next_sibling.hide();
                    } else {
                        next_sibling.show();                        
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }

    test_data_set( user_data );

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Coding decisions aside...
Try using `class` instead of `id` then you can take advantage of `this` selector via JS.

Answer (score 0):

@harigm, as you asked to post the code i have putting it, purely its not related to javascript. But Asp.net and VB.

```
 Protected Sub btnNew_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click   ''On New button or Cancel Button click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim selIndex As Integer
    If btnNew.Text = "New" Then                                 ''when New button is clicked

        Try
             btnChangePwd.Enabled = False
            DGLogin.Width = 1250
            selectedindexval = True
            DGLogin.Columns.Item(4).Visible = True
            DGLogin.Columns.Item(5).Visible = True
            btnDelete.Enabled = False
            btnDeleteAll.Enabled = False
            Bind()
            dt = Session("datatab")
            selIndex = dt.Rows.Count Mod DGLogin.PageSize
            DGLogin.CurrentPageIndex = dt.Rows.Count \ DGLogin.PageSize
            DGLogin.SelectedIndex = selIndex
            DGLogin.EditItemIndex = DGLogin.SelectedIndex
            Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
            dr("Userid") = String.Empty
            dr("UserName") = String.Empty
            dr("UserType") = String.Empty
            dr("Password") = String.Empty
            dr("EmailAlert") = False
            dr("EmailID") = String.Empty
            dr("SmsAlert") = False
            dr("PhoneNumber") = String.Empty
            dr("AlertOnWeekDays") = False
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            DGLogin.DataSource = dt
            DGLogin.DataBind()
            Dim ddlusType As DropDownList = DirectCast(DGLogin.Items(DGLogin.SelectedIndex).Cells(4).FindControl("ddlUserType"), DropDownList)
            ddlusType.Items.Remove("Administrator")
            ddlusType.Items.Remove("VP")
            Dim cnt As Integer = DGLogin.Items.Count
            For index As Integer = 0 To cnt - 1
                Dim lblPwd As Label = DirectCast(DGLogin.Items(index).Cells(5).FindControl("lblpwd"), Label)
                Dim lblconfirmPwd As Label = DirectCast(DGLogin.Items(index).Cells(6).FindControl("lblconfirmpwd"), Label)
                If lblPwd IsNot Nothing Then
                    If lblPwd.Text <> "" Then
                        Dim length As Integer = lblPwd.Text.Length
                        Dim strPwd As String = ""
                        For ind As Integer = 0 To length - 1
                            strPwd += "*"
                        Next
                        lblPwd.Text = strPwd
                        lblconfirmPwd.Text = strPwd
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            Dim chkemail As CheckBox = DirectCast(DGLogin.Items(DGLogin.SelectedIndex).Cells(7).FindControl("chkemailalertEdit"), CheckBox)
            Dim txtphone As TextBox = DirectCast(DGLogin.Items(DGLogin.SelectedIndex).Cells(10).FindControl("txtPhonenumber"), TextBox)
            Dim chksms As CheckBox = DirectCast(DGLogin.Items(DGLogin.SelectedIndex).Cells(9).FindControl("chkSmsalertEdit"), CheckBox)
            Dim EmailID As TextBox = DirectCast(DGLogin.Items(DGLogin.SelectedIndex).Cells(8).FindControl("txtemailid"), TextBox)
            Dim chkalertonweekdays As CheckBox = DirectCast(DGLogin.Items(DGLogin.SelectedIndex).Cells(11).FindControl("chkWeekdaysEdit"), CheckBox)
            chkalertonweekdays.Enabled = True
            chkemail.Enabled = False
            txtphone.Enabled = False
            chksms.Enabled = False
            EmailID.Enabled = False
            Dim txtusrid As TextBox = CType(DGLogin.Items(DGLogin.EditItemIndex).Cells(2).FindControl("txtuserid"), TextBox)
            txtusrid.Enabled = True
            txtusrid.Focus()
            txtusrid.Enabled = True
            Session("newrowadded") = True
            btnDelete.Enabled = False
            btnDeleteAll.Enabled = False
            btnNew.Text = "Cancel"
            btnEdit.Text = "Save"
            Session("soted") = False
            disablecheckbok()
            btnNext.Enabled = False
            btnlast.Enabled = False
            'btnfirst.Enabled = True
            'btnprevious.Enabled = True
            navigationButtouns()
        Catch ex As Exception
            UserMsgBox(ex.Message)
            WriteToLog(ex.Message)
        End Try
    ElseIf btnNew.Text = "Cancel" Then      'On click of Cancel Buttoun
        Try
            DGLogin.Width = 850
            selectedindexval = False
            DGLogin.SelectedIndex = -1
            If (Session("newrowadded") = True) Then
                If (DGLogin.EditItemIndex = 0) Then
                    DGLogin.CurrentPageIndex = 0
                End If
            End If
            btnChangePwd.Enabled = True
            Bind()
            DGLogin.Columns.Item(4).Visible = False
            DGLogin.Columns.Item(5).Visible = False
            DGLogin.EditItemIndex = -1
            DGLogin.DataBind()
            btnDelete.Enabled = True
            btnDeleteAll.Enabled = True
            btnNew.Text = "New"
            btnEdit.Text = "Edit"
            btnEdit.Enabled = True
            lblerror.Text = ""
            Session("soted") = False
            enablenavigationbuttouns()
            afterselectionchanged()
            EnableCheckBox()
        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteToLog(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

And its an Example to add a new row, to the grid when ever new button is clicked, and adding the columns to the grid will be normal in aspx page.

Comment: @ Thanks Kalyan, let me Check